# New Column is Doubling Value Based on Nested If Formula

Tags: powerbi, formula, dax, calculated-columns

I have a table that looks like this. [Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYzZ8.jpg)

**"FY 20-21 (Budgeted)"**, **"FY21 Approved Budget"** and **"Revised Budget"** are columns coming from three different data sources that I appended into one table. There isn't always data in all three of these columns, so I created a new column to consolidate the data with the following formula:

```
FY 20-21 Budget = 
if(
    and(
        isblank('Comprehensive Budget'[FY 20-21 (Budgeted)]),
        isblank('Comprehensive Budget'[FY21 Approved Budget])
    ),
    'Comprehensive Budget'[Revised Budget],
    if(
        and(
            isblank('Comprehensive Budget'[FY21 Approved Budget]),
            isblank('Comprehensive Budget'[Revised Budget])
        ),
        'Comprehensive Budget'[FY 20-21 (Budgeted)],
        'Comprehensive Budget'[Revised Budget]
    )
)
```

1. If both **Budgeted** and **Approved** are blank, use **Revised**.
2. If not, if both **Revised** and **Approved** are blank, use **Budgeted**.
3. If not, use   **Revised**.

But if you look on the screenshot, if NONE of the columns are blank, it gives me **Revised** plus **Budgeted**. Where is the problem in my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added your data here and found your Measure is perfectly returning your expected data as shown in the below image-

[image]

**I Guess,** there are some Aggregation issue in your case. You can right click on all column in the table visual properties and select **Don't Summarize** from the options. This should solve your issue I hope.